# Building a WPF App with NAnt

Tags: wpf, build-automation, nant

Is there some way to compile (with the CSC task) a WPF Application with NAnt except for using the `<msbuild>` task from the NantContrib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile a WPF application using CSC if you do not use any XAML in your application otherwise you will want to compile the WPF application using MSBuild.

Which con be done using the NAnt exec task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hoped I could avoid having to learn how to write msbuild files :(

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2005 and up then you can avoid it as all projects are already MSBuild files.  MSBuild also understands solution files.

Comment: Yes I know. I've been doing that all along, but I need to tweak some things in the buildfile .. So that's why I need to learn msbuild ;)